# Updating a region when you click on a button with ExtJS

Tags: javascript, dom, extjs, extjs4

Sorry for my newbness, I though this would be easy to do but I think I did not have understand sole basics in ExtJS :(.

My aim : I have a page with three containers.
The middle container is first blank.
When you click on a button, I want the the middle container to be changed to another one.

For this, I've made it :
 The first "blank" container :

```
var centerregion = Ext.create('Ext.container.Container', { 
border: false,
collapsible: false,
xtype: 'container',
id: 'centerregion',
items: [
    {
    border: true,
    xtype: 'window',
    visible: true,
    }, 
]
});
```

The container I want to be displayed when you click :

```
var consultation = Ext.create('Ext.container.Container', { 
border: false,
collapsible: false,
xtype: 'container',
id: 'consultation',
items: [
    {
    border: true,
    xtype: 'image',
    src: '/bundles/app/images/clouds.png',
    }, 
]
});
```

and then the listeners on the button :

```
listeners: {
click: function(){
    Ext.getCmp('centerregion').update('consultation');
}
},
```

When I click, it is "working", the centerregion is changed, but the new region only displays text "consultation.
So obviously, the

```
 Ext.getCmp('centerregion').update('bob');
```

will show a region displaying text "bob" as update() is waiting for html code.

Anyway, I don't think this is the right method to update a region.
Maybe I should have just one container, and updating it's content instead of calling another container ?
If someone has any tips :-) !

**Edit** : my page is constructed this way :

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
var mainscreen;
mainscreen = Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
    layout:'border',      
    items: [
        {
        layout: 'anchor',
        region: 'center',
        items: [
        maintopmenu,
        centerregion,
        ],
        },
        footer,
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's me again.
I finally found the answer this way

```
listeners: 
{
  click: clickMenu_Consultation,
},
```

and

```
function clickMenu_Consultation() {

 Ext.getCmp('centerregion').update(""); // Don't know if this is necessary, but it seems to be when the region is displaying HTML from AJAX
 centerregion.removeAll();
 centerregion.add({ 
     border: false,
     collapsible: false,
     renderTo: 'centerregion',
     xtype: 'container',
     id: 'referentiel_consultation',
     layout: 
        {
        type: 'vbox',
        align: 'center',
        pack: 'center',
        },
     items: [
        {
        xtype: 'box',
        html: '<h4>Bienvenue dans la gestion des référentiels<br><br>Veuillez choisir l\'entité à consulter</h4>', 
        margin: '20 0 20 0',
        },
        {
        width: 200,
        xtype: 'combobox',
        emptyText: 'Sélectionnez un référentiel', 
        margin: '0 0 10 0',
        },
        {
        width: 200,
        xtype: 'combobox',
        emptyText: 'Sélectionnez une entité', 
        margin: '0 0 20 0',
        },
    ]
 });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the component to the container like this:

```
centerregion.add(consultation);
```

### Edit:

```
var container = mainscreen.down('container');//the item without xtype in your case
container.remove(centerregion);
container.insert(1,consultation)
```

Comment: It does not work (already tried before posting). The previous element contained in centeregion is "fired" (?) but the new element contained in "consultation" is not displayed.

Comment: Prolly because the container "centeregion" seems to be destroyed after I click when inspecting the page with firebug. I've added some of my code above, maybe it can help.

Comment: Hmmm, I don't get what you did there. Where do I have to put this lines ? I tried with defining var mainscreen outside of the function but I get a 'cannot call method down of null'.

Comment: `down` is a function that gets a child from the object. I use this function to get the parent of `centerregion`. After that line I remove the `centerregion`. The last line I try inserting the `consultation` object in the place where formerly `centerregion` was displayed.

Comment: Oh Ok ! But I realize the way I want to do it seems wrong. Because I should have only one container, and update its contents. Because if I have a complex page, I'll have something like 50 differents containers, so it'll be too hard to use container.remove(x) for all of the containers that might be displayed. Maye I should look at AJAX.

Comment: `.remove` removes the child not the object you are calling it from. I guess you don't need AJAX because you have your object you want to display already.

Comment: Yeah, I guess that too. Still, can't make it work for the moment. I'll keep it updated if I find a solution.